# Can't target element with jQuery even though it's selectionable in the browser

Tags: jquery, target

[On my page](http://goo.gl/gD1mjZ) there are 5 white round buttons towards the center of the page. Clicking any of them displays a modal window which includes a "Close" button at the bottom of it. The markup of this button is:

```
<a href='#'class='button modal_close'>Close</a>
```

And the JS code I'm trying to attach to it is:

```
$('.modal_close').on('click', function() {  
    alert('test');
});
```

Yet clicking this button doesn't trigger any alert nor does it create any JS error in Firebug. I can target sub-parts of the modal window with the same result. Only if I target the entire modal container does it work.

What causes this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/x5x308pr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the modal content was dynamically generated, in which case the regular binding method fails. I fixed the problem by doing:

```
$(document).on('click','.modal_close',function(){
```

instead of:

```
$('.modal_close').on('click', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the click event listener to the element after it exists in the DOM (I'm guessing the `.on` attachment is happening onLoad, before the modal exists). Try attaching the click event listener in the code that opens the modal (after the elements have been created).